# Right way to update state object in redux react native

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I made a function to update state in React, one simple object. But I am not sure if it's correct way to do it because of immutable.
Can somebody say if it's right?

```
handleInputChange = (val) =>{
    // here -> some validation
    this.setState({myLimit: newVal})
  }
  submit = () => {
    let lim = {'lim':this.state.myLimit};
    this.props.updateLimit(lim);
  } 
  return (

     <TextInput 
      keyboardType ="numeric"
      autoCorrect={false}
      onChangeText={ this.handleInputChange }
      value={this.state.myLimit} 
     />
)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateLimit: (lim) => { dispatch(updateLimit(lim))}
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    limit: state.limit,
  }
}
```

rootReducer.js

```
const initState = {
  expenses:[
    { key: '1', sum: '100.67'},
    { key: '2', sum: '200.00'},
  ],
  categories: [
    { id:'1', name: 'a' },
    { id:'2', name: 'b' },
  ],
  limit: {lim:'1000'}  //<- this value I need to update
}

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    //some cases
    case 'UPDATE_LIMIT': {
      return {
        ...state,
        limit: action.lim
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

```
export const updateLimit = (lim) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_LIMIT',
    lim
  }
}
```

It work very well, but I guess there may be some mistake here as I change the state directly.
I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation will save whatever is passed to the action

```
const initState = {
  expenses:[
    { key: '1', sum: '100.67'},
    { key: '2', sum: '200.00'},
  ],
  categories: [
    { id:'1', name: 'a' },
    { id:'2', name: 'b' },
  ],
  limit: {lim:'1000'}  //<- this value I need to update
}

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    //some cases
    case 'UPDATE_LIMIT': {
      return {
        ...state,
        limit: action.lim // <-- this will create state.limit = <value>
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

So if for example you accidentally do `this.props.updateLimit(this.state.myLimit);` instead of `this.props.updateLimit({ lim: this.state.myLimit });`, the redux state shape will be off.

You'll probably want to adjust the action to simply take the new limit and handle the state shape internally in the reducer.

*Note: the `updateLimit` action creator already just takes a value.*

```
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    //some cases
    case 'UPDATE_LIMIT': {
      return {
        ...state,
        limit: {
          lim: action.lim, // <-- create the sub-key `lim`
        },
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now you can simply dispatch `updateLimit` with what you want the new limit to be, i.e. `this.props.updateLimit(this.state.myLimit);`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Drew. I am not completely understand and I think I got lost ... is it works because just one simple element in object?

Comment: If I will do something like this: case 'UPDATE_LIMIT': return Object.assign({}, ...state, { limit: state.limit.map(item => { return item.lim === action.lim ? action.lim: item; }). Will it somehow check it?

Comment: @Vova It works in your implementation so long as you send data with the correct shape, i.e. if it matches the existing state, so it's the caller's responsibility to *know* what that shape is so your state structure is maintained. I'm suggesting to flip it to make the reducer maintain the state structure so the caller need only submit a value they want to update. The reducer receives an action with value and the reducer knows where to store it. As for your second question, `limit` isn't an array so trying to map it won't work.